# Is the conjecture about prime numbers true?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime number.
Is it true that if $n$ is sufficiently large then will $$p_1×p_2×p_3×...×p_n+1$$ always be a composite number?

Comment: Almost certainly, the answer is not known.

Comment: It certainly doesn't have $\{p_1,\cdots, p_n\}$ as factors.  This construction was used by Euclid to prove that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: You should precise if your question is about the first or the second of these two statements: 1) There is a natural number $N$ such that $p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n+1$ is composite for every $n\ge N$. 2) For every natural number $N$ there is some $n\ge N$ such that $p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n+1$ is composite. Nevertheless, as @quasi has said, the answer is probably not known in either case.

Comment: This is an open question in number theory.  Heuristically, if anything, "Euclid numbers" are more likely than a random nearby number to be prime as noted by @Doug
https://oeis.org/A014545  
https://oeis.org/A006862

Comment: @DavidDiaz I didn't mean to suggest that $(p_1\times \cdots \times p_n) + 1$ is necessarily prime.  The construction merely proves that for any finite list of numbers, there exists a number co-prime to all all them.  And any finite list of prime numbers does not include all prime numbers.

Comment: Another relevant OEIS: http://oeis.org/A018239

Comment: Well, given what the largest primorial of this form, we know that $n\geqslant 33237$.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to explain why we always get a composite number.

**Case 1:** if these primes are arrange in ascending order and $p_1$ is 3 than:
$$p_1×p_2×p_3×...×p_n+1$$ 
is always a composite number as product of $n_th$ odd numbers (here primes) will always odd and adding 1 makes it even.

**Case 2:** if we take $p_n$ as 2 than $$p_1×p_2×p_3×...×p_n+1$$

will never be an even number as ($p_1×p_2×p_3×...×p_n$) will be even and adding 1 makes it odd.